# What's the purpose of this bulky cylindrical part near the plug end of a laptop charger cord?

Tags: charger, laptop

I want to fix my laptop charger cord, I used a multimeter to check the voltage and it gives me less than one volt. It feels very flexible near the plug, but I don't know if I can cut before or after the part marked in red. What is this part used for? Can I remove the red part?[image]

Comment: Also: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/133937/what-is-the-use-of-magnets-around-electrical-cables/

Comment: That help too, the problem is that the title of the question dont give much information

Comment: I agree this kind of question is really hard to search for. But also for the same reason your new question wouldn't be much help to future readers, so there's no real reason to keep more than one of these questions "active".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [ferrite bead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead). It suppresses high frequency noise.